React context does not recognize changes within a game object created
I'm currently creating a avatar chat using express and socket.io in the backend and react vite and socket.io-client in the frontend.
First I want to start by explaining the procedure:

User authenticates by sending a axios request to the backend. The backend assigns a httpOnly JWT header.
The user gets redirected to the home.jsx view and the local-storage data gets filled with values from the user object which the authentication process delivered.
At the same time a context will create the game object resulting with a socket connection being created etc.

After the socket.io connection was created it will emit data to the client to fill a array of room objects:
private sendRoomList = (socket: Socket) => {
  const roomData = this.rooms.map((room) => room.generateRoomClientData());
  socket.emit('chatroomList', JSON.stringify(roomData));
};

which the client will assign in the following way:
private setChatrooms = (clientData: string) => {
    this.rooms = []

    const roomData: RoomInterface[] = JSON.parse(clientData)

    roomData.forEach((roomObject: RoomInterface) => {
        const room = new RoomManager(
            roomObject.id,
            roomObject.name,
            roomObject.description,
            roomObject.participant_count,
            roomObject.capacity,
            roomObject.status,
        )

        this.rooms.push(room)
    })
}

So far it all works. Now the user can navigate to the chat.tsx view and gets greeted with a overview of rooms to select.
If the user selected a room it will send a emit message to the server containing the ID and navigate the user to the canvas which is the chat.
In the backend the client request will be received by the following function:
private joinRoom(socket: Socket, roomId: number) {
    const room = this.rooms.find((room) => room.id === roomId);
    if (!room) return;

    const player = this.findPlayerBySocket(socket);
    if (!player) return;

    const currentRoom = this.rooms.find((room) =>
      room.isParticipant(player.getId()),
    );

    if (currentRoom) {
      currentRoom.removeParticipant(player.id);
      player.resetCurrentRoom();
    }

    if (room.isFull()) {
      notification.errorMessage(socket, `${room.name} is full!`);
      return;
    } else {
      room.addParticipant(player);
      player.setRoom(roomId);
    }

    const clientData = room.generateRoomData();
    socket.emit('joinRoom', JSON.stringify(clientData));

    this.updateRooms(socket);
  }

This will set the data in the backend like update player count in a room etc. In the end of the function it will call the updateRooms function and deliver the updated room data to all connected users:
private updateRooms = (socket: Socket) => {
  const roomData = this.rooms.map((room) => room.generateRoomClientData());
  socket.broadcast.emit('chatroomList', JSON.stringify(roomData));
};

Which will call the same function setChatrooms shown in the beginning in this post for all connected users.
My problem is now the following: The room overview does not update the UI when a change inside the room array occurs.
The room component looks like the following:
import Container from '@/components/shared/Container'
import ContentHeader from './ContentHeader'
import { useGameContext } from '@/context/gameContext'
import RoomItem from './RoomItem'

interface RoomsProps {
    setSelectedRoomId: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number | null>>
}

const Rooms: React.FC<RoomsProps> = ({ setSelectedRoomId }) => {
    const { game } = useGameContext()

    return (
        <div className="page-container relative h-full flex flex-auto flex-col px-4 sm:px-6 md:px-8 py-4 sm:py-6 md:px-8 container mx-auto">
            <div className="mt-6 h-full flex flex-col">
                <Container className="h-full">
                    <ContentHeader title="Chat rooms" />
                    <div className="grid md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4 gap-4 mt-4">
                        {game?.rooms.map((room: any) => (
                            <RoomItem
                                key={room.id}
                                data={room}
                                setSelectedRoomId={setSelectedRoomId}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </Container>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Rooms

As in the code shown it gets the game context using const { game } = useGameContext()
and loops through all rooms inside the game?.rooms array and displays the data.
But it only updates the values if I refresh the site using F5 which then creates a new socket connection and receives the initial data with already updated data.
The data is for sure updated inside the game?.rooms array in the server and in the frontend. But the UI does not re-render and display the changes.
I think it has to do with the game context file.
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useAppSelector } from '@/store'
import GameManager from '@/game/manager/game.manager'
import { apiVerify } from '@/services/UserVerificationService'

interface GameContextValue {
    game: GameManager | null
}

const GameContext = createContext<GameContextValue>({
    game: null,
})

export const useGameContext = () => {
    return useContext(GameContext)
}

export const GameContextProvider = ({
    children,
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode
}) => {
    const [game, setGame] = useState<GameManager | null>(null)
    const auth = useAppSelector((state) => state.auth)
    const username = useAppSelector((state) => state.auth.user.username ?? '')

    useEffect(() => {
        try {
            if (auth.session.signedIn) {
                ;(async () => {
                    const result = await apiVerify({
                        username,
                    })

                    if (result) {
                        const gameInstance = new GameManager(result.data.id)

                        setGame(gameInstance)
                    }
                })()
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error initializing game:', error)
        }
    }, [auth])

    return (
        <GameContext.Provider value={{ game }}>{children}</GameContext.Provider>
    )
}

Within the context it checks also if the assigned local-storage username fits the JWT-token data. Else the game wouldn't be created.
What could cause this issue?

I only see one place where you call setGame (setGame(gameInstance) in GameContextProvider). Are there any others? The only way react knows to rerender is if you set state with a new value. Mutating an existing value will not cause a rerender

Ah okay, so i would have to remove the Gamecontext and use set state data for the objects. Thought i can set the game and the game itself would realize changes
